# Is white iPhone 3gs all white?

Tags: iphone

I am seeing images of iPhone white with only white background, while the front is black (or it looks on images). I am looking to buy used iphone 3gs and many images from different sellers are like this.

So, is white iphone 3gs all white or only the back of the phone is white? Or the front is of such color that black dominates and white cannot be seen on images?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. The white iPhone 3GS does not have a white face, just a white back cover.

[image]

Comment: @ipadoio No problem. If it answers your question, please mark it as "solved" so others that may visit it in the future can benefit.